# Advancing slideshow in jQuery

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I use this piece of code from tutorialzine:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    // The window.load event guarantees that all the images are loaded before the auto-advance begins.
    var timeOut = null;

    $('#slider_navigator .arrow, #slider_navigator .dot').click(function(e,simulated){
        // The simulated parameter is set by the trigger method.
        if(!simulated){
            // A real click occured. Cancel the auto advance animation.
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }
    });

    // A self executing named function expression:
    (function autoAdvance(){
        // Simulating a click on the next arrow.
        timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,2000);
        $('.slider_rightlink').trigger('click',[true]);
    })();

});
```

This works like expected except one thing, the first slide is immediately advanced when I load the page. After loading it rotates nicely with the rest of the slides.

How can I change this so that it shows the first slide 2 seconds like the rest?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function(){setTimeout(function(){

    // The window.load event guarantees that all the images are loaded before the auto-advance begins.
    var timeOut = null;

    $('#slider_navigator .arrow, #slider_navigator .dot').click(function(e,simulated){
        // The simulated parameter is set by the trigger method.
        if(!simulated){
            // A real click occured. Cancel the auto advance animation.
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }
    });

    // A self executing named function expression:
    (function autoAdvance(){
        // Simulating a click on the next arrow.
        timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,2000);
        $('.slider_rightlink').trigger('click',[true]);
    })();

},2000);}

);
```

There's probably a setTimeout jQuery function, but this will work.

Comment: Sometime life seems so complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

do not make it self executing function:

```
function autoAdvance(){
    // Simulating a click on the next arrow.
    timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,2000);
    $('.slider_rightlink').trigger('click',[true]);
};
timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,2000);
```

Comment: Subtle differences. This one, click in the first 2 sec will cancel. Walkerneo's, nothing is set up 'till first move.